# How do I store the results of each iteration of a for loop inside a variable

Tags: python, for-loop

I wrote the following code:

```
full_name = "John Francis Bean Coppola"
full_name_as_list = full_name.lower().split()

for name in (full_name_as_list):
a = name[0]
print(a)
```

When I run print(a) It returns:

```
j
f
b
c
```

I wanna define a variable like joined_results = something such that if I run print(joined_results) it returns:

```
jfbc
```

The purpose of the code I'm trying to write is to extract the initials of a name to create an e-mail address. For example: John Francis Ford Coppola = jffc@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

```
full_name = "John Francis Bean Coppola"
full_name_as_list = full_name.lower().split()

initials = []
for name in (full_name_as_list):
    initials.append(name[0])

#edit
print(''.join(initials))
```

Comment: Thanks! But that will return ['j', 'f', 'b', 'c']. I want the return to be jfbc. But I think I know how to do that now... Thanks!

Comment: apologies, I'll make that edit for future reference.

Comment: Thanks you so much! This is how I solved the problem: full_name = input("Enter name here: ")
full_name_as_list = full_name.lower().split()
first_name = full_name_as_list[0]+"-"
last_name = full_name_as_list[-1]
middle_names = list(full_name_as_list[1: -1])

initials = []
for name in (middle_names):
    initials.append(name[0])

print((first_name + '{}'*len(initials)).format(*initials) + last_name + "@gmail.com")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to join together all the items in a list.

```
print("".join([name[0] for name in full_name_as_list]))
```

Here, I'm joining the items together with a blank string, but for other applications, you can join them with anything, like so:

```
print("&".join([name[0] for name in full_name_as_list]))
```

would print

```
j&f&b&c
```